# Xamarin - Frame Shadow not showing properly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-5

I have a Xamarin Forms project and I'm trying to show frame shadow just like this

[image]

But instead it shows like this, the shadow is only appearing on the corners

[image]

I can't get it to show everywhere like the first picture

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:AppCrijoya.ViewModels" 
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:AppCrijoya.Models" 
             x:Class="AppCrijoya.Views.InvoicePage"
             x:DataType="viewmodels:InvoiceViewModel"
             Title="Facturas">
        <!--<ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <viewmodels:InvoiceViewModel />
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>-->

    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
            <CollectionView x:Name="ListViewCart" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ListCart}" 
                            SelectionMode = "Single"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding CartSelected}"
                            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding ShowAlertCommand}"
                            SelectionChangedCommandParameter="{Binding CartSelected, Source={RelativeSource Self}}"
                            >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Invoice">
                        
                            <Frame Margin="2" CornerRadius="30" HasShadow="True">
                                <Grid Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="160" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Nombre del Cliente:" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Image Source="arrow_dropdown.png" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalOptions="End"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fecha Compra:" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Date}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Monto Total:" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Total, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{0:N2}€'}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="Detalle Compra" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Color="Gray" HeightRequest="2" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

                                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="Nombre" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#9C2424"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="Monto" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#9C2424"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Text="Cantidad" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="#9C2424"/>

                                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                        <CollectionView x:Name="ListViewOrders" 
                                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOrders}" 
                                                        SelectionMode = "None"
                                                        >
                                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:CrOrder">
                                                  
                                                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0" MinimumHeightRequest="50">
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                <RowDefinition/>
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Reference}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="12" />
                                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:N2}€'}" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="12" />
                                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Quantity}"  TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="End" FontSize="12"/>
                                                        </Grid>

                                                   
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </CollectionView>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

What can I do to show the shadow all around the frame? Please help and thanks.

**EDIT**

This is what I have with Margin=2 on Frame

[image]

Margin=50

[image]

Padding=50

[image]

Just to show how it behaves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can create a new frame in your project to check if the cause is the renderer or not. Such as:

```
<Frame  Margin="20"  CornerRadius="10"  HasShadow="True">
   <Label Text="TestShaw" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</Frame>
```

If the shadow shows correctly, the cause maybe the layout or the margin of your frame. So you can change the values of it.

If the shadow shows incorrectly too, you may need to use a custom renderer for the frame. Such as:

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Myframe), typeof(MyFrameRenderer))]
  namespace App36.Droid
 {
    public class MyFrameRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FastRenderers.FrameRenderer
   {
    public MyFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        CardElevation = 50;
        SetOutlineSpotShadowColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black.ToAndroid());
        SetOutlineAmbientShadowColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Black.ToAndroid());
    }

  }    
}
```

But in my project, both of them shows correctly. So if you need more information, you can check the link following.

Link: [Xamarin forms Shadow on Frame in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505696/xamarin-forms-shadow-on-frame-in-android)

And here is the frame in my project:

[image]

If the platform is ios for your project, please check this case:[Forms frame isn't the same on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259233/forms-frame-isnt-the-same-on-ios)

Comment: Thanks! Adding a new frame works just fine but the one that I had already doesn't so I don't think is the renderer. I have been playing around with the margin but I can't get it right, I don't know what is causing that.

Comment: You can try to set a padding in the frame.@robluc

Comment: I have also tried that but doesn't work. I edited my question to show how the frame behaves when playing with the margin and padding

Comment: You can check this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7115), maybe you have the same problem which the shadow of the frame has been covered.@robluc

Comment: You can set the value of margin bigger to check it.@robluc

Comment: I have set the margin to 50 and still nothing. I'll check the link, thanks!

Comment: The link you provided solved my problem! Thank you!!!